# Hello, I would like to know how to use Enum in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums

I made an enum file and tried to import in the file showing next code (another file) 
But showing this error following :

```
File "C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/assignment3/Program.py", line 61, in Program
    NN.TrainByBackProp(100000, 0.1, GradDescType.STOCHASTIC)
NameError: name 'GradDescType' is not defined
```

and this host file seems not recognize import when I imported like import Myenum which is belonged enum file. What should I correct to deal with this issue? Thank you for your response in advance. If you need more information, let me know I will respond as soon as possible.

---

enum file

```
import enum

class GradDescType(enum.Enum):

    BATCH=1
    STOCHASTIC=2
    MINIBATCH=2

class ActivationFunction(enum.Enum):

    SIGMOID=1
    SOFTMAX=2
```

---

another file

```
NN.TrainByBackProp(100000, 0.1, GradDescType.STOCHASTIC)
```

Comment: if you use `import Myenum` then you need to use `Myenum.GradDescType.STOCHASTIC`

Comment: Did you import "enum file" into "another file"?

Answer (score 1):

In "another file" you need to import the two Enums you have defined:

```
from <enum_file> import GradDescType, ActivationFunction
```